# iOS Caches Directory handling relational files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfilemanager

I store certain files in the caches directory of my application because I want Apple to decide when to delete the files and I do not want them to be backed up.

However, some of these files relate to each other, for example:

1. Caches Directory

   - Custom Folder 1

     - File 1
     - File 2

If File 1 is deleted, then File 2 is pretty much useless. I was wondering if there is some way to tell the caches directory that these two files are related to each other, or better yet if the caches directory removes the entire Custom Folder 1 directory itself then that would be great!

Comment: Please add details. Are you using NSTemporaryDirectory, or NSCache, or something else?

Comment: I am using the CachesDirectory as mentioned in the title

Comment: I'm asking you to give us more details, not to repeat what's already there. :) **How** are you using CachesDirectory? Add an example of your code please. Without knowing how you;re doing it it's rather impossible to give a good answer to your question, it depends on the context and many parameters.